# What order are conditions evaluated in short circuit evaluation

Tags: ios, objective-c, short-circuiting

So I've got 3 conditions for an if-statements, and I want to ensure the first two are true before checking the third one. Here's some pseudo code demonstrating what I mean:

```
if (A && B && C) {
   doSomething
}
```

Is that equivalent to:

```
if (A && B) {
   if (C) {
      doSomething
   }
}
```

Or can we not rely on the ordering of the conditions in a short circuit evaluation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if ((A &&B) && C){}, but ordering will also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, short circuiting respects the order and will only evaluate until it finds a failure (hence taking a short cut when it knows it can't possibly succeed any more no matter how any future check might evaluate).

Comment: Perfect, exact answer I needed! I will accept in 8 minutes when it allows me too, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need all 3 to be true to execute the code, then both will fit your purpose.
Literally that statement reads if A and B and C are ALL true, execute that code. If however, you want to do something where A,B are true and C is false, you'll want to use your second piece of code and add an else statement